# Unity 3D - Collider bug in 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem with Unity 2D collider, shown in this video: https://youtu.be/AMof6lJNtNk

Red wall is "killing" me, but just after game start/respawn. I'm colliding with 2 walls (brick has smaller collider than red wall) and I'm dying, but if I first collide to brick, then to red wall I don't die. Why? 
I don't want to die in either case.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MovementScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 1.0f;
    Vector3 spawn;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        GetComponent ().freezeRotation = true;
        spawn = GetComponent ().transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        //Debug.Log ("Vertical: " + Input.GetAxis ("Vertical"));
        if (Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") > 0) {
            GetComponent ().velocity = new Vector2 (0, 1)*speed;
        } else if (Input.GetAxis ("Vertical")  ().velocity = new Vector2 (0, -1)*speed;
        }

        if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") > 0) {
            GetComponent ().velocity = new Vector2 (1, 0)*speed;
        } else if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal")  ().velocity = new Vector2 (-1, 0)*speed;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col){
        Debug.Log ("Koliduje!");
        if (col.transform.tag == "Respawn") {
            Debug.Log ("Skułeś się!");
            GetComponent ().transform.position = spawn;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some code as well.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PHdWcXZu

Comment: This " if (col.transform.tag == "Respawn") {" is being set by what? (tag's value)

Comment: GetComponent ().transform.position = spawn;
this is ur issue. u are moving your character position to spawn position when collision happens.

Comment: @Groude he doesn't if the tag is not Respawn, that's why I asked where he sets that...

Comment: @Mark yup, if the tag is true then its the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Red block has a Respawn tag (Im setting it on inspector -> Tag), but it first time collide for second time don't collide.